# Can evaporation of EtOH be slowed by adding dissolved solids to it? Does doubling the dissolved solid slow the evaporation in a predictable way?

Tags: evaporation

I use EtOH to dissolve shellac flakes for finishing procedure.  Does adding dissolved shellac slow the evaporation assuming all else is equal?  What if you double the amount of dissolved shellac.  Would that slow evaporation even more?

Comment: It does slow evaporation, but there can be problem with solubility or application issues with high concentration and viscosity.

Comment: BTW, if the goal is simply to dissolve shellac flakes, why not do that in a *closed* container? There would be *no* evaporation, and if the container is strong, it could be gently warmed to speed dissolution.